# Loading custom record in SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to load a custom record like below:

```js
var mergeRecord = record.load({
    type: record.Type.'custrecord_merge_vendor', 
    id: '12',
    isDynamic: true
});
```

This seems wrong.. but the equivalent for standard records is like below:

```js
var objRecord = record.load({
    type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, 
    id: 157,
    isDynamic: true,
});
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this:

```
var mergeRecord = record.load({
type: 'custrecord_merge_vendor', 
id: '12',
isDynamic: true
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You have the right idea, except that you are not passing the correct record type for your Custom Record into the `type` property. The correct value will just be the string that is your Custom Record's internal ID; it will start with `customrecord_`. You will not use the `record.Type` enumeration as that is only for native record types.

Because something like `record.Type.'custrecord_merge_vendor'` is not even valid syntax, I highly suggest you familiarize yourself with the fundamentals of the JavaScript language. You can find tons of introductory information and examples over at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide)